# Filter based on one column if its row's contents contains the elements of a list in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataset as follows:

```
            city  value
0   beijing city     23
1  shanghai city     34
2      guangzhou     45
3  shenzhen city     56
4     wuhan city     67
5      xian city     78
```

I would like to filter rows based on a list `cities = ['beijing', 'guangzhou', 'shenzhen']`

If the elements are contained in the `city` column, then filter out these rows.

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

The expected result:

```
            city  value
0   beijing city     23
1      guangzhou     45
2  shenzhen city     56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `str.contains()`:

```
m = df['city'].str.contains('|'.join(cities))
```

Finally:

```
out = df[m]
#OR
out = df.loc[m]
```

**Note:** If you have mixed format of word in the dataframe(uppercase,lowercase or title) then you can use `IGNORECASE` flag from `re` module so the 1st method become:

```
from re import IGNORECASE

m = df['city'].str.contains('|'.join(cities), flags = IGNORECASE)
```

Finally:

```
out = df[m]
#OR
out = df.loc[m]
```

Comment: I think your second solution is more general method, since in real data, not all the entries have space as delimiter to split.

Comment: @ahbon then use `str.contains()` with `IGNORECASE` flag (if needed)

Answer (score 1):

split city by space and pick desired str by index. Check occurance by str. contains

```
df[df['city'].str.split('\s').str[0].str.contains('|'.join(cities))]

    

            city   value
0   beijing city     23
2      guangzhou     45
3  shenzhen city     56
```

Following your comments below, use;

```
df[df['city'].str.split('\s').str[0].isin(cities)]
```

Comment: Thanks, if `beijingcity` is in `city`, I also want it to be filter out?